# How to find count of duplicate values as a percentage in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have eight columns in a table(birth_Record) of a hospital record. The record is considered duplicate if the below three columns are the same

DATE_AND_TIME                    Baby_Name               Mother_Name
(date and time
when a baby was born)

I have to find a query which returns the number of duplicates in the last 3 months and also gives the percentage of the duplicate records out of the total records in last 3 months.

I have written the below query is it correct?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantities,
       COUNT(Baby_Name) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(Baby_Name) FROM birth_Record) AS percentage
FROM birth_Record
WHERE DATE_AND_TIME >= DATEADD(M, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP BY Baby_Name, DATE_AND_TIME, Mother_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: I am using SQL 2019 @ToniAntunović. The RTM version is 15.0. 2000.5.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expceted result? Why do you ask if your query is correct instead of trying out? Maybe it would be better to tell us what is incorrect in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data so I made my test table:

```
create table test1 (col_1 varchar(2),col_2 varchar(2),col_3 varchar(2),col_4 float, col_5 float, col_6 date);
insert into test1 values ('a','b','c',1,2,'2022-05-20 10:34:09');
insert into test1 values ('a','b','c',6,9,'2022-04-10 10:34:09');
insert into test1 values ('k','l','m',1,2,'2022-04-20 10:34:09');
insert into test1 values ('k','l','m',11,2,'2022-01-20 10:34:09');
insert into test1 values ('k','l','m',1,2,'2022-02-20 10:34:09');
insert into test1 values ('k','l','c',7,0,'2022-03-20 10:34:09');
```

Here we are counting duplicates where only col_1,col_2 and col_3 are relevant
with a window function and then calculating the percent of that count out of total row count in the last 3 months:

```
select col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5, count(*)over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_3) dupl_number,
       round(cast(count(*)over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_3) as float)/cast((count(*)over())as float)*100,2) dup_percentage
from test1
where col_6>DATEADD(MONTH, -3, CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ))
```

In your case col_1,col_2 and col_3 would be:
`DATE_AND_TIME` `Baby_Name` `Mother_Name`
in the `count(*)over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_3)`
and col_4, col_5 would be some irrelevant columns, if you leave col_4 and col_5 out and write distinct after select you would get: 1 row per distinct col_1,col_2,col_3 value with its count and percentage of total counts:

```
select distinct col_1,col_2,col_3, count(*)over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_3) dupl_number,
       round(cast(count(*)over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_3) as float)/cast((count(*)over())as float)*100,2) dup_percentage
from test1
where col_6>DATEADD(MONTH, -3, CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ))
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4efcb3b3d3a77d06fb5b8dd985c8863d)